# Touch screen's PushButtons are not working properly in PyQt/PySide6 Windows Application

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside, touchscreen

I have a GUI application written in Python using the PySide6 library. All the things are working perfectly with mouse. However, problems happened when I clicked the buttons on a 10" USB-touch screen monitor. The pushbutton pressed/ released signal will only be trigger after i removed my finger from touch screen. The touch/ mouse event is in the order `TouchBegin -> TouchEnd -> MouseButtonPressed -> MouseButtonReleased`. From Qt document, I know that QWidget.event() translates the first non-primary touch point in a `PySide.QtGui.QtouchEvent` into a `PySide.QtGui.QMouseEvent`. However, this is not what i want. I would like the button be pressed once i put finger on the button and be released once i remove finger. I found a guy who met [similar problem](https://forum.qt.io/topic/115928/qpushbutton-touch-screen-issue) but didn't come up with a solution.

I have written a simplified version of my application to show the problem. Here is the code of main.py:

```
    import sys, time, threading, logging
    from PySide6.QtCore import *
    from PySide6.QtGui import *
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import *
    from PySide6.QtSvgWidgets import *
    from ui_touch_screen_test import Ui_MainWindow

    class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
        def __init__(self):
            super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
            self.setupUi(self)

            self.isLooping = False
            self.pushButton.pressed.connect(self.button1_pressed_thread)
            self.pushButton.released.connect(self.button1_released)

        def eventFilter(self, watched: QObject, event: QEvent) -> bool:
            if event.type() == QEvent.TouchBegin:  
                print(f"touch begin  : {watched.objectName()}")
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.TouchUpdate:  
                print(f"touch update  : {watched.objectName()}")
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.TouchEnd:  
                print(f"touch end  : {watched.objectName()}")
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonPress:  
                print(f"MouseButtonPress  : {watched.objectName()}")
                return True
            elif event.type() == QEvent.MouseButtonRelease:  
                print(f"MouseButtonRelease  : {watched.objectName()}")
                return True

            return super().eventFilter(watched, event)

        def button1_pressed_thread(self):
            buttonPressedThread = threading.Thread(target=self.button1_pressed)
            buttonPressedThread.start()

        def button1_pressed(self):
            self.isLooping = True 
            while self.isLooping:
                print("button1_pressed")
                time.sleep(0.2)

        def button1_released(self):
            self.isLooping = False 
            print("button1_released")

    QCoreApplication.setAttribute(Qt.AA_SynthesizeMouseForUnhandledTouchEvents, False)
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.setAttribute(Qt.WA_AcceptTouchEvents, True)
    window.installEventFilter(window)
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

code of `ui_touch_screen.py`:

```
    from PySide6.QtCore import (QCoreApplication, QDate, QDateTime, QLocale,
        QMetaObject, QObject, QPoint, QRect,
        QSize, QTime, QUrl, Qt)
    from PySide6.QtGui import (QBrush, QColor, QConicalGradient, QCursor,
        QFont, QFontDatabase, QGradient, QIcon,
        QImage, QKeySequence, QLinearGradient, QPainter,
        QPalette, QPixmap, QRadialGradient, QTransform)
    from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QFrame, QMainWindow, QPushButton,
        QSizePolicy, QVBoxLayout, QWidget)

    class Ui_MainWindow(object):
        def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
            if not MainWindow.objectName():
                MainWindow.setObjectName(u"MainWindow")
            MainWindow.resize(541, 404)
            self.centralwidget = QWidget(MainWindow)
            self.centralwidget.setObjectName(u"centralwidget")
            self.frame = QFrame(self.centralwidget)
            self.frame.setObjectName(u"frame")
            self.frame.setGeometry(QRect(9, 19, 521, 371))
            self.frame.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
            self.frame.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
            self.widget = QWidget(self.frame)
            self.widget.setObjectName(u"widget")
            self.widget.setGeometry(QRect(70, 110, 411, 176))
            self.verticalLayout = QVBoxLayout(self.widget)
            self.verticalLayout.setObjectName(u"verticalLayout")
            self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.pushButton = QPushButton(self.widget)
            self.pushButton.setObjectName(u"pushButton")
            self.pushButton.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton {\n"
    "   border: 2px solid gray;\n"
    "   border-radius: 10px;\n"
    "   padding: 0 8px;\n"
    "   background-color: rgb(40, 42, 54);\n"
    "   font: bold 60px;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "   background-color:rgb(0, 255, 127);\n"
    "}\n"
    "QPushButton:hover:!pressed {\n"
    "   background-color:rgb(51, 54, 69)\n"
    "}\n"
    "")

            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

            self.pushButton_2 = QPushButton(self.widget)
            self.pushButton_2.setObjectName(u"pushButton_2")
            self.pushButton_2.setStyleSheet(u"QPushButton {\n"
    "   border: 2px solid gray;\n"
    "   border-radius: 10px;\n"
    "   padding: 0 8px;\n"
    "   background-color: rgb(40, 42, 54);\n"
    "   font: bold 60px;\n"
    "}\n"
    "\n"
    "QPushButton:pressed {\n"
    "   background-color:rgb(0, 255, 127);\n"
    "}\n"
    "QPushButton:hover:!pressed {\n"
    "   background-color:rgb(51, 54, 69)\n"
    "}\n"
    "")

            self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)

            MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

            self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)

            QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)
        # setupUi

        def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
            MainWindow.setWindowTitle(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"MainWindow", None))
            self.pushButton.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Button 1", None))
            self.pushButton_2.setText(QCoreApplication.translate("MainWindow", u"Button 2", None))
        # retranslateUi
```

result when I touch and release from the blank area:

```
touch begin  : MainWindow
touch end  : MainWindow
MouseButtonPress  : MainWindow
MouseButtonRelease  : MainWindow
```

result when i touch and release on the button:

```
touch begin  : MainWindow
touch end  : MainWindow
button1_pressed
button1_released
```

I don't understand why the button1_pressed function is triggered but no MouseButtonPressed event is printed. Also, why the `watched.objectName()` is not pushButton and is MainWindow instead? I pressed on the button, i suppose pushButton is what i get.

I would like the button be pressed once i put finger on the button and be released once i remove finger. Anyone can give some advice how i can achieve that? Many thanks.

---

### UPDATE

I found i can do what i want by adding a `self.pushButton.pressed.emit()` inside the eventfilter function. When i touched on the screen, it triggered the function immediately as i wanted, but the background color of the button didn't change.

Also, how can I eliminate the mouseButtonPressed and mouseButtonReleased which are automatically generated when i release my finger for touch screen?